# bootstrap numbered of rows in table

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to make a table with bootstrap. I've found that it's actually possible to do something alike to auto-increment. The example could be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/DominikAngerer/yx275pyd/2/

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-
    url="/gh/get/response.json/wenzhixin/bootstrap-
    table/tree/master/docs/data/data1/">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-formatter="runningFormatter">Index</th>
      <th data-field="name">Name</th>
      <th data-field="stargazers_count">Stars</th>
      <th data-field="forks_count">Forks</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

and using following jscript

```
function runningFormatter(value, row, index) {
  return index;
}
```

The problem is its using data from remote url. can i do something similiar with a table that has some preset values by my already? the goal of this is that i could prepend new rows to table and it would index rows. the starting table could look something like this:

```
<table class="table table-inverse">
    <thead class="thead-default">
        <tr>
            <th data-formatter="runningFormatter">Index</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Job</th>
            <th>Wage, €</th>
            <th>bla, €</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
            <td>bla</td>
            <td>blum</td>
            <td>
                <p class="btn" style="width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-
                bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></p>
                <p class="btn" style="width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-
                bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
            <td>bla</td>
            <td>blum</td>
            <td>
                <p class="btn" style="width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-
                bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></p>
                <p class="btn" style="width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-
                bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If anyone know how index column could go like this 0001, it would be wonderful

Comment: you can get new index by count the table row

Comment: not sure how to do this to be honest. i think i have an idea how i could display somewhere total number of lines, but not how to increment rows as if there is 3 lines, top one should be 1, lower one 2, then 3, etc.

Comment: $("#myTable > tbody > tr").length in Jquery